# Setinterval not firing at individual times - and uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the function on this code, `whatareyousingingpatrick(),`, when the function is called a new element and setinterval should be called, however it doesn't seem like a new one is created with a new `original` variable, it just seems like the same one gets fired over and over. Thanks for your help

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<body onclick="whatareyousingingpatrick();" onkeypress="pretend();">
<span id="money">25</span>$ - <span id="lives">100</span>/100 lives - Level: <span id="level">1</span>
<br><br>
<span style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:1000px;height:175px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;display:block;" id="track"></span>
<br>
<span id="divthing" style="position:relative;display:block;"></span>


<script>
  money = 25;
  lives = 100;
  mycars = {};

  function doofus() {
    if($("div:first").offset().left > 1000){
      $("div:first").remove();
      lives = lives-1;
      document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = lives;
    }
  }

  function dodat() {
    var btn = document.createElement("div");
    btn.style.width = "25px";
    btn.style.height = "25px";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    btn.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
    btn.style.position = "absolute";
    btn.style.left = "0px";
    btn.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 1s";
    var numba = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
    btn.class = "haha";
    btn.id = numba;
    mycars[numba] = -50;

    var move = function () {
      mycars[numba] = mycars[numba] + 1.5;
      document.getElementById(numba).style.left = mycars[numba] + "px";
      if(mycars[numba] > 100 && mycars[numba] < 150){
        document.getElementById(numba).style.top = mycars[numba]/0.5-200 + "px";
      }
    };

    setInterval(move, 10);

    document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
  }

  setInterval(dodat, 2000);
  setInterval(doofus, 200);

  function dis1() {
    $("shooter").css("background-color", "red");
    setTimeout('$("shooter").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl = $("#shoot1");
    // Let's find the closest block!
    var otherEls = $('div'),
    compareTop = compareEl.offset().top,
    compareLeft = compareEl.offset().left,
    winningScore = Infinity,
    score, winner, curEl;

    otherEls.each(function () {
      // Calculate the score of this element
      curEl = $(this);
      score = Math.abs(curEl.offset().left - compareLeft);
      if (score < winningScore) {
        winningScore = score;
        winner = this;
      }
    });
    document.getElementById(winner.id).style.opacity="0";

    money = money+1;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
  }

  function dis2() {
    compareEl2 = $("#shoot2");
    // Let's find the closest block!
    var otherEls2 = $('div'),
    compareTop2 = compareEl2.offset().top,
    compareLeft2 = compareEl2.offset().left,
    winningScore2 = Infinity,
    score2, winner2, curEl2;

    otherEls2.each(function () {
      // Calculate the score of this element
      curEl2 = $(this);
      score2 = Math.abs(curEl2.offset().left - compareLeft2);
      if (score2 < winningScore2) {
        winningScore2 = score;
        winner2 = this;
      }
    });

    document.getElementById(winner2.id).style.opacity="0";
  }


  function dis3() {
    compareEl3 = $("#shoot3");
    // Let's find the closest block!
    var otherEls3 = $('div'),
    compareTop3 = compareEl3.offset().top,
    compareLeft3 = compareEl3.offset().left,
    winningScore3 = Infinity,
    score3, winner3, curEl3;

    otherEls3.each(function () {
      // Calculate the score of this element
      curEl3 = $(this);
      score3 = Math.abs(curEl3.offset().left - compareLeft3);
      if (score3 < winningScore3) {
        winningScore3 = score;
        winner3 = this;
      }
    });

    document.getElementById(winner3.id).style.opacity="0";
  }


  function dis4(){
    compareEl4 = $("#shoot4");
    // Let's find the closest block!
    var otherEls4 = $('div'),
    compareTop4 = compareEl4.offset().top,
    compareLeft4 = compareEl4.offset().left,
    winningScore4 = Infinity,
    score4, winner4, curEl4;

    otherEls4.each(function () {
      // Calculate the score of this element
      curEl4 = $(this);
      score4 = Math.abs(curEl4.offset().left - compareLeft4);
      if (score4 < winningScore4) {
        winningScore4 = score;
        winner4 = this;
      }
    });

    document.getElementById(winner4.id).style.opacity="0";
  }

  original = 0;
  function whatareyousingingpatrick(){
    if(money >= 1){
      money = money+10000000;
      original = original+1;
      setInterval("dis"+original+"();alert("+original+");", 1800);
      var btn = document.createElement("shooter");
      btn.style.display = "block";
      btn.id = "shoot"+original+"";
      btn.style.height = "25px";
      btn.style.width = "25px";
      btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      btn.innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/1317280976_1370202845.png' style='height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:100%;opacity:0.7;'>";
      btn.style.borderRadius= "100%";
      btn.style.boxShadow= "0px 0px 200px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
      btn.style.position = "absolute";
      btn.style.left = event.pageX-20;
      btn.style.top = event.pageY-250;
      document.getElementById("divthing").appendChild(btn);
    }
    else{
      alert("Sorry, this dude costs over 25 bucks.");
    }
  }

  function pretend(){
    if(money >= 60){
      money = money-60;
      if (event.keyCode == 49) {
        alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your first missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
        setInterval("dis1();", "1000");
      }
      if (event.keyCode == 50) {
        alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your second missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
        setInterval("dis2();", "1000");
      }
      if (event.keyCode == 51) {
        alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your third missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
        setInterval("dis3();", "1000");
      }
      if (event.keyCode == 52) {
        alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your fourth missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
        setInterval("dis4();", "1000");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Sorry, the cost of the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for this missile is 60$");
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("level").innerHTML="2";setInterval(dodat, 8000);', '40000');
</script>
<br><br>
```

Here it is isolated.

```
  original = 0;
    function whatareyousingingpatrick(){
    if(money >= 1){
    money = money+10000000;
    original = original+1;
        setInterval("dis"+original+"();alert("+original+");", 1800);
            var btn = document.createElement("shooter");
            btn.style.display = "block";
            btn.id = "shoot"+original+"";
            btn.style.height = "25px";
            btn.style.width = "25px";
            btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            btn.innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/1317280976_1370202845.png' style='height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:100%;opacity:0.7;'>";
            btn.style.borderRadius= "100%";
            btn.style.boxShadow= "0px 0px 200px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
            btn.style.position = "absolute";
            btn.style.left = event.pageX-20;
            btn.style.top = event.pageY-250;
            document.getElementById("divthing").appendChild(btn);
    }
    else{
    alert("Sorry, this dude costs over 25 bucks.");
    }
    }
```

When I try:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var func = 'dis' + original;
    func();

    alert(original); //for some reason
}, 1800);
```

I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`. Any clue why?

Comment: Once the values are passed to an interval, you can't change them, you'll need a recursive function for that.

Comment: why is that, how would that be accomplished? :) @adeneo

Comment: func() is not a function. Why do you call it as a function?

Comment: can you give me an example of how else i could do it? @SalGad

Comment: Can you try eval(func) instead of 'func()' in your last bit?

Comment: SalGad would avoid using eval. It's a significant security risk

Comment: Doesn't work! @SalGad I'm fine with it, even if there's a risk but i cant get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a function on a string variable.

var func = 'dis' + original;

so func is now a string not a callable function.

If the resultant string func is actualltly a function name you could do this:

```
window[func]();
```

To call func with a string variable.

Comment: now, it doesn't work once I place the second tower, the second time the interval is called. http://dumbsearch.com/tdg.php

Comment: So if you compare the variable func, does it match a global function name? If so the above should work.

Comment: i dont quite understand

Comment: you can address javascript functions one of two ways.
dis1(); or window["dis1"](); Provided a global function named dis1 exists.

Comment: but wait, everytime there is a new setinterval, if I set `func()` as a global it will overwrite each time. any solution?

Comment: The code shows you how to call a function with the function name as a string. You are calling the function not assigning a new function.